# List with float:left facing issue

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css-selectors

I have a scenario where I need to show list items horizontally....
except the first list items. All the other items has `margin-left` property but if the list items are more then it goes down that is not so good.

Here is the plunker link:
[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/GLQCooGMMlrmVnba5MX3?p=preview)

I need the down items(8,9,10) should also  align properly as the first row elements. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: links to plunker must be accompanied by code in the question itself

Comment: I've removed the angular-material tag as it is not related. Hope that's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed `first-of-type` selector to `last-of-type` and `margin-left` to `margin-right`. Check the updated plunker here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/XZDYi37LWZGeU10HvWdC?p=preview

```
li:not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```

Comment: It's working fine but we also need some space between the rows right

Comment: Yeah, I guess just add `margin-bottom:10px` or so - or `margin-bottom:5px; margin-top:5px` for symmetry

Answer (score 1):

Apply `margin-right`

```
li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```

or else apply `margin-left` for `li` and try negative margin for ul

```
ul{
    margin-left: -40px;
}
li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 30px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If `flexbox` is an option, you can do this - put in a *wrapping* flexbox with `flex-start` property along the *flex-axis* - see demo below and [**`updated plunkr here`**](https://plnkr.co/edit/7a28noQVVyEWnmpIZ4ZB?p=preview):

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 30px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't to try this with bootstrap. You can have a layout with screen/container divided into seven(or any as its is configurable. Usually the screen is divided into maximum 12).

And instead of li, you can simply have a **div** element for displaying the items.